# A pairwise disjoint open cover induced by an arbitrary open cover

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that I have an open cover $\lbrace U_{i} \rbrace_{i \in I}$ of a topological space $X$. Can one induce from such an open cover another open cover $\lbrace V_{\alpha} \rbrace_{\alpha}$ such that $V_{\alpha}\cap V_{\beta}= \emptyset$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$ ? .

Comment: $\{X\}$ is an open cover of $X$  that meets your criterion.... If $X$ is a connected space and $C$ is any open cover of $X$ with $X\not \in C,$ then the members of $C$ cannot be pair-wise disjoint.

Comment: "induce" is what? subcover (then obviously no), refinement (no, as this means $0$-dimensional)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you finally have a disjoint open cover so take any open set $A$ from that disjoint open cover, and call the union of all the other open sets in the disjoint open cover to be $B$.

So $X=A\cup B$, $A$,$B$ both open and $A\cap B=\phi$, hence such a space must be disconnected, so any connected topological space would serve as a counter-example.

Comment: However, is it possible to construct a pairwise disjoint cover from the given cover that is not required to open ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ is compact and connected set and $X \subseteq \lbrace U_{i} \rbrace_{i \in I}$ and let assume $\lbrace V_{j} \rbrace_{j \in J}$ is such open cover of $X$ you mentioned then it has a finite sub cover due to compactness of $X$. this sub cover is also pairwise disjoint that make $X$ disconnected !  contradiction !